# how to move Activity of Main Application to activity of sub application in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

How can I move  Activity from Main Application Actitvity(name is MainActivity) to 
sub Application Activity(name is MainActivity)

public void listAllActivities() throws NameNotFoundException, ClassNotFoundException
    {

```
    List<PackageInfo> packages = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);

    for(PackageInfo pack : packages)
    {

        if (pack.packageName.equals("com.ABC.example")){

            ActivityInfo[] activityInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(pack.packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES).activities;

        Log.i("PC", pack.packageName + " ::: ");

             if(activityInfo!=null)
            {
                for(int i=0; i<activityInfo.length; i++)
                {
                    Log.i("actlist", pack.packageName + " ::: " + activityInfo[i].name);

                    if(activityInfo[i].name.equals("com.ABC.example.MainActivity")){

                        Log.i("activity", pack.packageName + " ::: " + activityInfo[i].name);

                        Intent i1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,activityInfo[i].name.getClass()); 
                        startActivity(i1);

                    }
                }
            }           
        }
    }       
}
```

log cat :

11-08 12:00:19.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1184): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

11-08 12:00:19.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1184): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pride/com.example.pride.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=com.ABC.example/.MainActivity } from ProcessRecord{40684d90

1184:com.example.pride/10034} (pid=1184, uid=10034) requires null

11-08 12:00:19.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)

11-08 12:00:19.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)

11-08 12:00:19.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)

11-08 12:00:19.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)

11-08 12:00:19.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

11-08 12:00:19.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

11-08 12:00:19.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)

11-08 12:00:19.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

Comment: What is a "sub Application Activity"?

Comment: thanks this is com.ABC.example.MainActivity I want to move on from main Appication Activity

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand your question, nor what you are trying to do, nor what your problem is.

Comment: Is a possible to move on one Application to another application through their activity?

Comment: You don't move "on one application to another". You move "from one application to another". Sometimes using the correct words helps a lot! ;-) Also, these aren't "sub applications". There is no concept of a "sub application " in Android. It is just another applcation.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch an `Activity` of another application from your application, as long as it is publicly available (`"exported="true"` or it has an `<intent-filter>`). You are doing this:

```
    Intent i1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,activityInfo[i].name.getClass()); 
    startActivity(i1);
```

This won't work because you have used the 2-argument `Intent` constructor. This constructor takes the "package name" from the first argument (this will contain your application's package name) and the class name for the activity from the second argument.

You want to do this:

```
    Intent i1=new Intent();
    i1.setClassName(activityInfo[i].packageName, activityInfo[i].name); 
    startActivity(i1);
```

This way, you are setting the package name and the activity class name using the information from the `ActivityInfo` object.

Comment: Thank you so much give your time and solution.

Comment: but I am still not figure out through this way so, another app publicly available means? this is when working ? I got now still to the information only. without use Intent.

Comment: Its not Allow me access SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent

Comment: please paste the logcat in the question. Don't filter it. There should be an error and possibly a stacktrace.

Comment: its give me runtime exception with securityException: so is it Work to move on one app to another ?

Comment: Of course you can start another application. It may be that the activity you are trying to start is not "public". Please past the information from the logcat in your question (just edit your question and paste the error messages at the end).

Comment: I need a more explaination  to understand this.. thank you so much

Comment: I opened a chat room here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/64619/question-26757048 I don't know if you have enough reputation to chat.

Comment: I keep com.ABC.example.MAinActivity   activity in manifest too! but still same problem and error

Comment: Please copy the manifest for "com.ABC.example" into the question so I can see it. I don't think you understand how this works.

Comment: <activity
            android:name="com.ABC.example.MainActivty">
        </activity>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64707/discussion-between-david-wasser-and-ghanshyam).

Comment: Your application package is "com.example.pride". You are trying to start an activity from another application package "com.ABC.example". You can't just add this to your own manifest. Is the other application yours? If so, please post the manifest from the other application.